# typeof error comparing to undefined - data is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prestashop

I've got a bit of code that's kicking of an error for me - and I can't seem to find a way around it or a good solution in javascript.

```
        var data = new FormData();

        $.each(files, function(key, obj)
        {
            data.append(obj.name, obj.file);
        });

        data.append('submitCustomizedDatas', 1);
        data.append('ajax', 1);
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#customizationForm').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.errors === 'undefined')
            {
                $.each(files, function(key, obj)
                {
                    $('input[name="'+obj.name+'"]').addClass('filled');
                    previewFile($('input[name="'+obj.name+'"]'), obj.file);

                });
                $('.uploadingfiles').text('Upload Complete!');
            }
            else
            {
               $('.uploadingfiles').text('Error while uploading, please refresh the page and try again');
            }
            $('.myoverlay').click(function(){$(this).remove()});
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
           $('.uploadingfiles').text('ERRORS: ' + errorThrown);
            $('.myoverlay').click(function(){$(this).remove()});
        }
    });
```

This is used for the upload of files on a site I'm making.

This bit of Ajax is kicking off an error in JS console when it hits success.  The error is saying 'data is null' at this line:

```
if(typeof data.errors === 'undefined')
```

Just curious if this looks right, or if there might be something really obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: Is there anything coming in the body of the response to the network request or is it completely empty?  Although, I would expect that to be an empty string.  But since you're saying it should be `json` it may very well come in as null.  If the response **is not** empty, is it valid `json`?

Comment: Actually, read [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation.  Under **dataType - "json"**.  If you're using "json" for a dataType, you should handle `null` or `{}`.

Comment: if I do an alert for (data) it just alerts 'null'

Comment: Also, bear in mind that `null !== undefined`.  So you will have to handle `null` or `{}` explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, [the opening brace placement matters](http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/).  Your code might not mean what you think it means due to your placement of the opening brace.

Also, the use of .success and .error have been deprecated.  [Consider using .done or .fail methods.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Typeof null returns an object, so if data.errors is null, your check will fail.  Consider doing

```
if (!data.errors) {
    ...
}
```

Lastly, the data being returned from the server might be null.  This would cause the null exception that you are seeing.  You can debug your application to see if this is the case.

Comment: I did something close and went with a falsy: "if (!data)" - which works.

I adjusted my ajax for .done and .fail accordingly as well.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The error you described, "data is null...", is very precise. JavaScript throws an error when you try to access a property from a `null` object. In this case, you are trying to access the `errors` property of the `data` object, which is `null` in that case (your server is not returning anything).

You should probably verify the data object before making any other assumptions:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (data !== null) { // first make sure data is not null
        if(typeof data.errors === 'undefined') { // then you can safely trust this line
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Watching the `jqXHR.status` could be a way of finding out what is going on with your server.

**EDIT:** in fact, I recommend always using the server response's status code to check for errors:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 200) { // 200 - Success
        // Everything went well
        // ...
    } else {
        // Something went wrong
        // console.log(textStatus);
        if (data !== null) { // first make sure data is not null
            if(typeof data.error !== 'undefined') { // // check if the server has returned any error information
                // handle specific error
                // console.log(data.error);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: So I've been revisiting this for a number of reasons - if the data being returned is 'null', does that mean it's not successfully posting to the server?

Comment: Not necessarily. In fact, it is a common pattern to return null as a response to a POST request, but it can theoretically return anything you (the developer) want. The right way of verifying if a request was successful or not is to verify status code in the response through jqXHR.status as I mentioned. A well implemented server will always return the right status codes.